# On model change re-render, some nested attributes disappears

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

I have the following message backbone setup:

```
  class InboxItemView extends Backbone.View
    initialize: ->
      @model.on('change', @render, @)
    render: ->
      @$el.html JST['buy/messages/templates/received_message'](@model.toJSON())
      @

  class InboxListView extends Backbone.View
    items: []
    initialize: ->
      @collection.on('reset', @reset, @)
    reset: ->
      _.each @items, (item) -> item.remove()
      @items = _.map @collection.received(), (model) =>
        item = new InboxItemView(model: model)
        @$('tbody').append item.render().el
        item
```

Model

```
  class Message extends Backbone.Model

  class Messages extends Backbone.Collection
    model: Message
    url: '/messages'
    received: -> @filter (message) -> message.get('receiver').id == gon.userId
```

Rabl:

```
object @message
attributes :id, :title, :body, :read_at, :created_at, :last_reply

node :path do |message|
  message_path(message)
end

child :sender => :sender do
  attributes :id, :nickname
end

child :receiver => :receiver do
  attributes :id, :nickname
end
```

During the initial render everything displays properly. However when I changed the model and the list item gets re-rendered, the model's sender hash becomes empty. Therefore the render will not print out the name of the sender. Attributes likes title still displays, since they are not the nested.

Why does the nested attributes disappear? Am I rendering some intermediate model?

Comment: Having the same problem right now.

Comment: sorry for late update, but somehow my problem disappears a few months ago. @Chris_Bui Do you want just edit and add your example below my question? Probably easier for others to debug your issue.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to try is, in your `InboxItemView`'s `render` method, `console.log(@model, @model.toJSON())`. Using the web inspector or firebug, expand the resulting objects and see how they differ, if at all. There's no real reason fields would be dropped, so you need to figure out what is in the model and what is coming out of `toJSON`.

Answer (score 1):

We would need to see your controller to confirm, but my suspicion is that when you save the model it is getting an updated response that goes through a different rabl template than the one posted.